# Child div full width - margins

Tags: html, css

I have a nested set of divs. I want an inner div to get the full width without using more width than the parent div and the left and right margins. I tried max-width:100% but it didn't worked so far. In this example `#test2` should be full width - margin-left

HTML

```
<div id="test">
    <div id="test2">
        <div>123</div>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="test3"></div>
```

CSS

```
#test{
    width:100%;
    height:100px;
    float:left;
}
#test2{
    margin-left:51px;
    float:left;
    width:100px;
    max-width:100%;
    background:blue;
    height:100px;
}
#test3{
    width:50px;
    float:left;
    background:red;
    height:100px;
    margin-left:-100%;
}
```

[JS FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/LHSfQ/1/)

I would like to get it working without using javascript or any new CSS command like `calc`
Any pointer?

Comment: I don't get what you want, can you explain more?

Answer (score 0):

try this,

```
min-width:100px;
width:100%;
```

Answer (score 0):

Take away width:100px; and make it width:100%; like this:

```
#test2{
margin-left:51px;
float:left;
width:100%;
background:blue;
height:100px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this:

`FIDDLE`

I hope it solves your problem.